# Definition of expectation $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}$ ( over an initial distribution $\mu )$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

Hello Math StackExchange!

I am very frustrated trying to find the definition of $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}$ (apparently it means expectation with initial distribution). I have tried to search on many different platforms and books , but am in vain.

Also, is it true that $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[X] = \sum_{s} \mu(s)\hspace{1mm} \mathbb{E} [X_{n} | X_0 = s]$ ?

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you give an example of where you have seen this used.  I have sometimes seen this notation used as you say w.r.t initial distribution, for instance if $X_t$ is some stochastic process at time $t$ then $E_\mu[X_t]$ is the expected value of $X_t$ given $X_0 \sim \mu$.

Comment: In the context of Markov chains/processes: $\mathbb E_\mu[\:\cdot\:]=\int\mu(\mathrm dx)\,\mathbb E[\:\cdot\mid X_0=x]$.

Comment: @nejimban Yes, as suspected (I had earlier edited my question). However, I am more interested in the discrete version of the definition. Do you have a source or something for this? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: @DanielAdams here is a source (https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~yadina/RWnotes.pdf) on p. 14 Proposition 2.14.

Comment: @DanishA.Alvi on those notes, $\mathbb P_\mu$ (or $\mathbb E_\mu$) is defined in the middle of page 13.

Comment: Ah yes! For the probability $\mathbb{P}_\mu$, not for expectation (perhaps I really need to carefully see, sincere apologies if I missing it).

Comment: @DanishA.Alvi Expectation $\mathbb E$ (or $E$, $\mathbb E_\mu$, …), given a probability measure $\mathbb P$ (or $P$, $\mathbb P_\mu$, …) is generally defined as $\mathbb E\,f=\int f\,\mathrm d\mathbb P$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130515/discussion-between-danish-a-alvi-and-nejimban).

Comment: @nejimban Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conversation with @nejimbam, I used the definition from p. 13 of the notes I shared ([https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~yadina/RWnotes.pdf](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/%7Eyadina/RWnotes.pdf)).

$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[X] = \sum_{x} \mathbb{P}_{\mu}[X=x] \cdot x  \hspace{45mm} \text{(By def. of $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}$)}\\
 \hspace{11mm}= \sum_x \big[ \sum_s\mu(s) \hspace{1mm}  \mathbb{P}[X=x | X_0 = s] \big] \cdot x \hspace{13mm} \text{(By def. of $\mathbb{P}_{\mu}$ as shared in the notes)}\\
 \hspace{11mm}= \sum_x \sum_s\mu(s) \hspace{1mm}  \mathbb{P}[X=x | X_0 = s]\cdot x \hspace{17mm} \text{(Distributivity of Summation)}\\
 \hspace{11mm}= \sum_s \sum_x \mu(s)\hspace{1mm}  \mathbb{P}[X=x | X_0 = s]\cdot x \hspace{17mm} \text{(Switching order of Sums)} \\
\hspace{11mm}= \sum_s \mu(s) \sum_x\mathbb{P}[X=x | X_0 = s]\cdot x \hspace{17mm} \text{(Rearranging)}\\
\hspace{11mm}=\sum_s \mu(s) \hspace{1mm} \mathbb{E}[X=x | X_0 = s] \hspace{29mm} \text{(By def. of $\mathbb{E}$)}$

I am sorry if this was trivial and “expected” to be known (pun is intended here), but I prefer clear, rigorous definitions / derivations.